# How to install extension in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to install extensions through `cmd.exe/command prompt` or `command line interface` in visual studio code please giv some example for better clearity and understanding and also how do i change the integrated terminal for eg i have cmder i want to change to it i have seen the preference file but i got confused

Comment: Did the tutorial microsoft provides not give enough information?  It looks like they give pretty detailed instructions.  Please provide more information on what you have tried.

Comment: @Matt i have readede the doc but i got so confuse/didnt understand thats why i asked here check the following link also [Issue on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14155)

Comment: The GitHub issue is not any more detailed than your post here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Visual Studio Code extensions from Command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286515/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-extensions-from-command-line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this will help you.  Visual studio has a built in console in the form of "package manager console".  You can use this for installing packages and other command-line things related to Visual Studio.  It's in the UI at the bottom, all you need to do is look for it.

Otherwise, Visual Studio also includes a special version of the command prompt as a separate application, which you can use to run operations specific to Visual Studio.  This is located in the same portion of the Start Menu in Windows as the rest of the Visual Studio applications.

Other than that, here are the links to the top two google search results for the exact question in your title:

[Managing Extensions in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/extension-gallery)

[Installing Extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/extensions/install-extension)

It seems to me Microsoft has provided some pretty solid documentation here.  Please provide more information about what you have tried if these things are not enough.

Comment: give some eg how to install extension via cmd lke `code --install-extension extensionName'

Answer (score 1):

From powershell, assuming default install dirs:

`& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code" --install-extension [extension publisher].[extension name]`

So, for example, to install the Intant Markdown previewer made by David Bankier, we look in VSCOde and see that the fully resolved name is `dbankier.vscode-instant-markdown`.

So we execute

`& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code" --install-extension dbankier.vscode-instant-markdown`