# install a downloaded vsix extension in Visual Studio code fro windows for all users

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to find out how i can install a downloaded vsix extension into Visual Studio code so that the extension is available for all users of that Windows machine.

i see answers on how to install extensions for current user here:
[How to install Visual Studio Code extensions from Command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34286515/559144)

but I need something working for all users on the machine.

Comment: there is 1 directory with user extensions, not 2 or 3

Comment: thank you very much, i understand now what you meant, i logged in with the other user and manually copied all extensions folders from one user profile to another and all works now. THANKS