# Coding Pack for Java - Silent install?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, silent

Is there a Windows silent install for the Coding Pack for Java? I have JavaCodingPack-0.4.1.exe and I have tried /? to no avail and tried various other switches. Trying to get this together for a class of coders.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java

There was no silent installation I could see.

Answer (score 1):

If already have VS Code installed, you can install extensions [via the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286515/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-extensions-from-command-line):

```bash
# Install the Java Language Pack
code --install-extension vscjava.vscode-java-pack
```

Here are the extensions included in the Java Language pack:

| Name | Identifier | Included |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) | `vscjava.vscode-java-pack` | N/A |
| [Language Support for Java™ by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) | `redhat.java` | Yes |
| [Debugger for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-debug) | `vscjava.vscode-java-debug` | Yes |
| [Test Runner for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-test) | `vscjava.vscode-java-test` | Yes |
| [Maven for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-maven) | `vscjava.vscode-maven` | Yes |
| [Project Manager for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-dependency) | `vscjava.vscode-java-dependency` | Yes |
| [IntelliCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode) | `visualstudioexptteam.vscodeintellicode` | Yes |

Recommended:

| Name | Identifier |
| --- | --- |
| [Spring Boot Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vmware.vscode-boot-dev-pack) | `vmware.vscode-boot-dev-pack` |
| [Gradle for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-gradle) | `vscjava.vscode-gradle` |
| [Community Server Connectors](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-community-server-connector) *(for Apache Felix, Karaf, Tomcat, Jetty, etc.)* | `redhat.vscode-community-server-connector` |
| [Server Connector](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-server-connector) *(Red Hat Servers, for example Wildfly)* | `redhat.vscode-server-connector` |
| [Extension Pack for MicroProfile](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MicroProfile-Community.vscode-microprofile-pack) | `MicroProfile-Community.vscode-microprofile-pack` |
| [CheckStyle](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shengchen.vscode-checkstyle) | `shengchen.vscode-checkstyle` |
| [SonarLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarlint-vscode) | `SonarSource.sonarlint-vscode` |

Other noteworthy extensions:

| Name | Identifier |
| --- | --- |
| [Java Code Generators](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sohibe.java-generate-setters-getters) | `sohibe.java-generate-setters-getters` |

Comment: @Warthog is Java on the path? Is JAVA_HOME set? Here is an excellent guide on [setting up VS Code for Java development](https://dev.to/robole/setting-up-vs-code-for-java-development-4c49).